# Ideas for microbiology lab. Antimicrobial properties of cutting boards

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology, experimental-design, experiment

I am an undergraduate student in Biology and I am trying to design a microbiology lab that will takes 3 weeks to carry out (1-2 day each week). I am going to examine the antimicrobial properties of cutting boards. So far I have determined that I will use bamboo vs plastic and dish-soap vs disinfectants. I will be using two bacterial strains *E.coli* and *S.epidermis*.

Week 1: MIC (Minimal Inhibitory Concentration) assay of disinfectants and soap and prepared LBA (lysogenic Broth Agar) plates for viable counts during week 2.

Week 2: Inoculated cutting boards wait 30, 60, and 120 mins wash with various products then swab cutting boards with sterile swab, place swab in test tube with saline vortex and plate the resulting liquid on LBA. Count CFU (colony forming units) during the week.

Week 3: **This is where I'm stuck the experiment has to last three weeks but I'm not sure what other tests I could carry out on the third week.**

Any advice would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: Did you plan on doing statistics to compare your treatments?  Statistical analysis could be your "Week 3"

Comment: I do plan on doing statistical analysis but that will be done outside the lab I was looking for another type of assay or different types of treatments I could do in lab. Thanks, @Dirigible

Comment: In my experience in biology, usually if everything goes as well as possible then Week 3 is for repeating the thing that went wrong in weeks 1 or 2. If everything goes normally, then Week 3 is for repeating Week 1 and Week 4 is for repeating Week 2.

Comment: I am afraid that however much one sympathizes with the problems of setting up laboratory classes for students, that is not included in the remit of this site, which is to answer questions about biology itself.